# If $\{x_n\}\to 0$ and $y_n=\frac{x_1-x_2-...-x_n}{n}$ then $\{y_n\}\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I'm trying to prove that if $\{x_n\}\to 0$ and $y_n=\frac{x_1-x_2-...-x_n}{n}$ then $\{y_n\}\to 0$. One can easily show that $\left| y_n\right|<x_{max}$, but this doesn't seem to tell us much.

I'd appreciate any hints on how to prove the above.

Comment: Well $y_n = \frac{x_1}{n} - \sum \limits_{i=2}^n \frac{x_i}{n}$, which is asymptotically just $-\sum \limits_{i=2}^n \frac{x_i}{n}$. Now you can solve it or Google the solution pretty quickly.

Comment: Didn't find anywhere what how to sum $\frac{x_i}{n}$. Can you please elaborate? We don't know what $x_i$ is for any $i$.